# How to determine if there is an sbyte type inside the object?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to determine if there is an sbyte type inside the object?

```
void Do() {
   object obj = func();
   bool isSByte = obj.GetType() is sbyte; //not correct
}
object func() {
   object obj = new sbyte(-124);
   return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is (this variant preferable)

```
bool isSByte = obj is sbyte;
```

GetType

```
bool isSByte = obj.GetType() == typeof(sbyte);
```

Check inheritance:

```
// sbyte
bool isInherits = typeof(sbyte).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()); // true

// for classes
bool isMemoryStreamInheritsStream = typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MemoryStream));  // true (MemoryStream based on Stream)
```